# subprocess in python: file does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, macos, subprocess

I run into this error while trying to launch an application from my Mac by using subprocess command.

I tried this and it still working normally

```
import subprocess

appname = "Microsoft Word"
appname1 = appname + ".app"
subprocess.Popen(["open", "-n", "/Applications/" + appname1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But however, when I applied it to my function. It said the file does not exist.

```
import re
import subprocess

def myCommand(command):
    elif 'launch' in command:
        reg_ex = re.search('launch(.*)', command)
        if reg_ex:
            appname = reg_ex.group(1)
            appname1 = appname + ".app"
            subprocess.Popen(["open", "-n", "/Applications/" + appname1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And it returned like this:

```
Command: Launch Microsoft Word
The file /Applications/ microsoft word.app does not exist.
```

Comment: Is the space between /Applications/ and "Microsoft word" word a typo or is it actually there in the error message? If it is actually there, that could be your problem... maybe try a regex that eliminates a no y spaces between the launch word and the rest of the expression? E.g. `re.search('launch\s*(.*)'`

Comment: @GMc: Ohhh, it worked. Thanks man. I was really silly not to realize the problem is in the space between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that your regex captures the space before the argument of `launch`, resulting in a full filename like `/Applications/ microsoft word.app` instead of `/Applications/microsoft word.app`

That (or a simple `str.split` or better: `shlex.split`) would fix it:

```
re.search('launch\s+(.*)', command)
```

note that `'launch' in command` is a bit fragile to detect if the command is really `launch`. What if the *arguments* contain `launch`. Use `shlex.split` to be able to parse your command line properly (with quote support) instead:

```
import shlex

command = ' launch "my application"'

args = shlex.split(command)
# at this point, args = ['launch', 'my application']
if args[0] == "launch" and len(args)==2:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["open","-n",os.path.join("/Applications",args[1])],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: OMG! It worked. And thank you for the advice man. I definitely gonna use that.